# Reference for generalization of the cosine function in 2 space for spectral method such that the basis is orthogonal?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

So for a 1-d spatial, and 1-d time PDE,

I represent the solution as $U_N= \sum_{n=0}^N c_n(t) \phi_n(x)$,

where $\phi_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(nx)$ and $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$

I was curious if anyone had suggestions on how to generalize this to 2-d spatial dimension. e.g $x\in [-\pi,\pi]^2$.

I hypothosized that it would look perhaps like this:

$U_N= \sum_{n,m} c_n(t) \phi_{n,m}(x)$

where $\phi_{n,m}=\frac{1}{\pi}cos(nx_1)cos(mx_2)$, but I could not find a reference that confirmed my hypothesis.

Does anyone have suggestions, or can confirm that I am correct?

Comment: Yes, that is a reasonable assumption, with a minor correction that $\phi_{n,m}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{\pi}\cos(n x_1)\cos(m x_2)$. (I think you have a typo because you re-use $x_1$ in the second argument.)

Comment: I did, my mistake! Thank you for taking the time to give me this feedback!